# Error installing Anaconda: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, anaconda

I am attempting to install Anaconda. I have made sure that I do not have any other versions of Python and removed the versions that were installed with Visual Studio. When I try to install the Anaconda for Python 3.7 for 64 Bit, I get the following error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

Current thread 0x00003f38 (most recent call first):

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... done

Solving environment: ...working... failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
```

Any idea of what is causing this error and how I can solve it?

Thank you,
Susan

Comment: Do you run your installer as a su/sudo/Run As Administrator ?

Comment: On my company laptop, I run as power broker which should have the same permissions.

Comment: What is your os?

Comment: Windows 10. Sorry, I should have added that to the problem description. It is the 64 bit version OS.

Comment: in your  windows CMD type : ```net user %username%```  and in ```Local Group Memberships```section check if you have administrators permissions

Comment: I do have sub admin. I can install and make changes as long as they do not affect the operating system. So, I can install Visual Studio, but the help desk had to install SQL Server for me because my permissions weren't high enough because it required a change to the OS.

Comment: It is obvious that you must get help from your network/system administrator, he/she will be install it for you ( or in illegal  way you can exploit your laptop  with existing privilege escalation exploits :) )

Comment: Admin was able to install without issue. He also updated my permissions. Thank you.